# Is connecting to a Network means that I am connecting to a WiFi

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, wifimanager

Given that, i have only `WiFi` networks available on the device and no `mobile` networks, only `WiFi`.

If I cheecked the connectivity to a network using `connectivityManager` and the result of it is that "I am connected", does that mean I am also connected to a `WIFI`also? If yes, why I can not get info about my `WiFi` such as `ssid`,`speed`, `link speed`, `ip` and others from the `Connectivity Manager` object? Because, to have such info you have to be connected to a `WiFi` first.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you are connected & connected to a Wifi

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                      activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
boolean isWiFi = activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
```

You can use Wifi Manager to get the information about Wifi Network

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
```

More info on the WifiInfo
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html

Answer (score 0):

I think being connected to a network indicates that you are connected to the internet whether through WiFi, Mobile network, Bluetooth or any other network.

And if you are connected to the internet through a WiFi, then, of course, you have connected to a network but through a specific network.

So, the `connectivity manager` class, has all the network info about the network through which you are connected to the internet. and since it is a generic class you can obtain info about the network through which you are connected to the internet.